# Flex: Simulating a click on a button inside an item renderer of a data grid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I'm using a **data grid with an item renderer** that creates a toggle button. **The idea is to have a list of items and only allow one to be selected and pre-select one at start.**

I've got the single button selection working, meaning that when I click on on toggle button, the others are deselected.

My problem is to create a way of pre-selecting an element of the data grid or simulate a click on a row and selecting the corresponding toggle button.

If I use the datagrid.selectedIndex the result is a selection but the toggle button doesn't get selected.

Here is the code example

In this example **I am using the array value "selected" to define selected button**, not my favourite solution but the one that worked first.

The array collection:

```
public static const ValuesList : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
    [
    {ID:0, Name:"One", selected:false},
    {ID:1, Name:"Two",       selected:false},
    {ID:2, Name:"Three",         selected:false},
    {ID:3, Name:"Four",  selected:false}
    ]
);
```

The data grid:

```
<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider={ValuesList} >
 <s:columns>
    <s:ArrayList>
        <s:GridColumn id="GridCol0" />
        <s:GridColumn id="GridCol1" />
        <s:GridColumn id="GridCol2" itemRenderer = "detail_ItemRenderer" />
    </s:ArrayList>
 </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

The column item renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                    clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        /**
         * Creatioon complete event handler to set toggle button content value.
         * */
        protected function MyToggleButton_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent) : void
        {
            MyListToggleButton.label = data.Name;
            MyToggleButton.selected = data.selected;
        }

        /**
         * One of the only function that are called on item interaction.
         * */
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
            MyToggleButton.selected = data.selected;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:ToggleButton id="MyToggleButton" width="100%" height="100%"
                creationComplete="MyToggleButton_creationCompleteHandler(event)" />

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

SOLUTION:

Using the data array to pass information into the Toggle button. Setting one value to "true" will display the selected element.

To insure data integrity I advise to set the selected index of the grid to the corresponding index of the value set to "true":

```
public function SetSelectedIndexByName() : int
{
for (var i : int=0; i < dataGrid.dataProvider.length ; i++)
{
    if (dataGrid.dataProvider[i].toString().toUpperCase() == "TRUE")
    {
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;
 }
```

Comment: I don't see the code in there that handles the toggling.  Without knowing how you are doing that part, it's difficult to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GridItemRenderer`, you should overwrite the setter of `data`. Your data will contain a variable defining the selection of the `ToggleButton`. In the setter you will be able to toggle the button based on this variable.

To have only one button selected, you may use a static variable in your renderer which stores the selected itemrenderer. This one is simpler but not really clean since it's a matter of data, not renderers. So you may listen for any change in the dataProvider from a higher level and ensure there's only one item selected.

Comment: I had implemented a solution pretty much close to what you describe and thank you for the detailed explanation. This action eventually lead to a solution.